# How to improve response from Llama2 2b model using langchain for address classification?

Tags: prompt, langchain, large-language-model

I am using Llama2-2b model for address segregation task, where i am trying to find the city, state and country from the input string. The problem is simple, when the input string doesn't have any of these entities, it still returns this entity [i want it to return not present]
How do i force it to return entities from only the string ?

Ex :

```
input : "32, Panaji Beach Road, Panaji, Goa"
output : City: Panaji
         State: Goa
         Country: India # this should be "Not present"
```

## Code :

```
address_template = """
Answer the question without explanation.

What is city, state and country in "{address_string}".
"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables = ['address_string'],
    template=address_template,
)



from langchain.chains import LLMChain

chain = LLMChain(llm=llm,
                 prompt=prompt,
                 verbose=True)
string1 = "32, Panaji Beach Road, Panaji, 403001, India"
# Run the chain only specifying the input variable.

print(chain.run(string1))
```

I understand that i have to change the address template i have tried adding 'Just answer from the string' / return 'Not present' if city, state or country is not present. It doesn't work.

Thanks.